# Discrete math functions (Onto, One-to-One) Proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

Let $f : \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ and $g : \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ be functions defined by $f(x) = 3x + 1$ and $g(x) = \lfloor x/2\rfloor$ (this is floor of x/2) for each $x\in\mathbb Z$

1. Is $g\circ f$ one-to-one? Prove your answer.
2. Is $g\circ f$ onto? Prove your answer.
3. Is $f\circ g$ one-to-one? Prove your answer.
4. Is $f\circ g$ onto? Prove your answer.

What I am thinking to try is to prove they are inverses, then I can conclude that they are both onto and one-to-one. However, I am told that they are not inverses?

Comment: Hi and welcome! A few things: please always tell us **what you've tried** and **where you're stuck**; try to phrase posts as if you were talking to somebody, **not as commands**; please **use MathJax for maths** (see e.g. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: To get things started: do you know what one-to-one and onto mean? Do you have any guesses for any of these answers, even if you can't think of a proof or counterexample? If you have answers to my questions or anything else to add, be sure to either make a comment, or add information to your question by clicking the [edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/466242/edit) button.

Comment: Thanks guys, I know what Onto and One-To-One is, but can't think of proving it. An idea would be, if I prove that f and g are inverses, wouldn't that help?

Comment: Proving that $f$ and $g$ are inverses would certainly prove that they are both one-to-one and onto. However, two functions being inverses is a ***much*** stronger condition than their compositions being one-to-one or onto, so most of the time that you're able to prove the latter, you ***won't*** be able to prove the former.

Comment: So I guess I am looking for some ideas then...

Comment: So as Omnom... suggested, (2) is not onto. It's generally relatively easy to prove something is not onto. Have you been able to prove (2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a push in the right direction:

Note that $f$ is not onto, because given an integer, it will only yield numbers that are one more than a multiple of three. In particular, we know there is no $x$ such that $f(x)=0$.  What can we then say about $f\circ g$?

Note that $g$ is not one-to-one, because it will yield the same output for an even number and its odd successor.  In particular, we note that $g(1)=g(0)=0$.  What can we then say about $f\circ g$?

That should take care of $f\circ g$.  Now, for $g\circ f$:

Is there any $x$ for which $g(f(x))=4$?

What would we be able to deduce if we could show that $g(f(x))$ is a strictly increasing function?

---

Answers so far:

$f\circ g$ is neither one to one nor onto.

It is not onto because there is no $x$ such that $f(g(x))=0$.  It is not one to one because $f(g(0)) = f(g(1))=1$

$g\circ f$ is one to one but not onto.

It is not onto because there is no $x$ such that $g(f(x))=4$.  It is one to one because for any $x\in\mathbb Z$, we find that
$$
\begin{align}
g(f(x+1)) &= \left\lfloor\frac12(3(x+1)+1) \right\rfloor\\
&= \left\lfloor\frac12(3x+1)+\frac32 \right\rfloor\\
&\geq \left\lfloor\frac12(3x+1) \right\rfloor + 1\\
&>\left\lfloor\frac12(3x+1) \right\rfloor
=g(f(x))
\end{align}
$$
That is, $g(f(x))$ is strictly increasing since for any integer $x$: $g(f(x+1))>g(f(x))$.

This means that for any integers $x,y$: $x>y$ implies $g(f(x))>g(f(y))$.

This means that $g(f(x))$ must be one to one.

---

To some of the points in the comments:

Your proof that $g\circ f$ is one to one was as folllows:

> Suppose $g(f(a))=g(f(b))$.  That is, 
>   $$\lfloor (3a+1)/2\rfloor = \lfloor (3b+1)/2\rfloor$$
>   It follows that
>   $$
> \frac12(3a+1)-1<\frac12(3b+1)<\frac12(3a+1) + 1 \implies\\
> 3a + 1 - 2 < 3b + 1 < 3a + 1 + 2 \implies\\
> a - 2/3 < b < a + 2/3
> $$
>   It follows that if $a,b$ are both integers, we must have $a=b$.  Thus, $g\circ f$ is one to one.

That works! Good proof.

> "Two functions f o g are onto if and only if both f and g are onto".

False. Consider $f,g:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ given by $g(x)=2x$, and $f(x) = \lfloor x/2\rfloor$. Note that $g$ is not onto, but $f\circ g$ is onto. Also, note that $f$ is not one to one, but $f\circ g$ is one to one.

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, I am still not sure about this. I know that if f is not onto, then `f` o g is not onto. Right? So, if that is true, I need to come up with a counter-example to prove that f o g is not onto?

Comment: So your counterexample would be the following: there is no $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(g(x)) = 0$, since there's no $y\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(y)=0$.  Because $f\circ g$ doesn't map any number to $0$, $f\circ g$ is not onto, so $0$ is our counterexample here.  We can make a similar statement about $f\circ g$ not being one to one.  What can we say after checking $f(g(1))$ and $f(g(0))$?

Comment: Thanks, for b) I did what you said, basically: Two functions f o g are onto if and only if both f and g are onto. But f is not onto. As Ey in Z such that Ax in Z, F(x) not equal to y. For example, let y = 0, then there is no F(x) = 0. The same goes for f o g, right? working on other ones now.

Comment: Please tell me if that is correct? thanks very much for the help.

Comment: How about this for a) Let a and b be integers, and let g◦f(a) = g◦f(b).
⌊(3a + 1)/2⌋ = ⌊(3b + 1)/2⌋
(3a + 1)/2 - 1 < (3b + 1)/2 < (3a + 1)/2 + 1
3a + 1 - 2 < 3b + 1 < 3a + 1 + 2
3a - 2 < 3b < 3a + 2
a - 2/3 < b < a + 2/3
Since a is the only integer in that interval, a = b.
The function g◦f(x) is one-to-one.

Comment: You are wrong in saying that $f\circ g$ is onto iff $f$ and $g$ are onto. The key point is that $f\circ g$ can only be onto if $f$ is onto, and $f\circ g$ can only be one to one if $g$ is one to one. You can use the particular counterexamples I've provided.  As for the other two: $g(f(x))$ never is $4$, which means $g\circ f$ is not onto. $g\circ f$ is strictly increasing, which means that it is one to one, as your proof demonstrates, I think

Comment: I've edited my question to include the answer to some of your questions.  Let me know if you'd like anything clarified.

Comment: I tried this for b) Let g◦f(x) = 1.
⌊(3x + 1)/2⌋ = 1
1 ≤ (3x + 1)/2 < 2
2 ≤ 3x + 1 < 4
1 ≤ 3x < 3
1/3 ≤ x < 1
But there are no integers on this interval.
Therefore there is no x on the domain of g◦f(x) such that g◦f(x) = 1.
The function g◦f(x) is not onto. Any mistakes?

Comment: No mistakes! Well done, you've shown that $g\circ f$ is not onto.  Do you understand everything in the latest version of my answer?  At this point, I think you should be all set

Comment: Yeah... got it. Thanks for the help.